# Query By example and boolean field

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, query-by-example

In class Users, I have a field id, firstname, lastname, username, password, enabled.

Enabled field is boolean

When i use do this query by example with spring

```
Users users = new Users();
users.setId(12);
Example<Users> example = Example.of(users);
Page<Users> pageUsers = userRepository.findAll(example, page);
```

In the generated query, i see in the where condition, it search on id field and enabled

why it's search on enabled?

Comment: Could you paste the code of Users class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using "boolean" primitive type, so your "Example" object has implicitly the "false" value.. you can use "Boolean" type to fix it

Comment: You can do like that if you don't want to change the type to "Boolean" : 

Users users = new Users(); users.setId(12); 
ExampleMatcher exampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnorePaths("enabled"); 
Example<Users> example = Example.of(users, exampleMatcher); 
Page<Users> pageUsers = userRepository.findAll(example, page);